# Using self and parameters in a Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to use self (for global variables) and the parameters from the command-line in my Python Script but can't really get them to work.

```
def otherFunction(self)
    print self.tecE

def main(argv,self):
    self.tecE = 'test'
    otherFunction()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:],self)
```

This gives me an error:

```
    main(sys.argv[1:],self)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

So how and where to define `self`?

Comment: What is `self` in main?

Comment: `self` is normally only used in combination with classes ... I assume you copy pasted this code (mainly the different functions) from somewhere else (where the class-keyword has been used) - without understanding it.

Comment: I'd like to use it in a way as `this` is used. Wouldn't mind to make a class out of it, but is there some kind of template for the usage of global variables and parameters for a simple script to be run in the command line?

Comment: There is no special handling of ``this`` or ``self``, they are just variable names. No matter if within or outside of a class. You have to define them just like any other variable. It's just a convention to use ``self`` within a class to reference the current class instance.

Comment: What do you mean with `this`? `this` is Java, not Python. The python class syntax is a bit different then the java syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141/classes-in-python

Comment: @MikeScotty You got some kind of template for that? I'm unable to mange using the parameters and global variables at the same time

Comment: Template for what? A template that tells you that you have to define variables before you can use them?

Comment: @quant - I'm a Java developer trying to understand the concept of python

Comment: @MikeScotty - not that kind of template. I mean just an example code that shows how global variables and command line parameters are used in the same script. So far I'm only able to manage either of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the python convention of `self` is to be used in python classes, you did a bit of a mess.

So either you are not using classes and treating self just as a global dict, like this:

```
import sys
myglobal = {} # Didn't want to name it self, for avoiding confusing you :)

def otherFunction():
    print myglobal["tecE"]

def main(argv):
    myglobal["tecE"] = 'test'
    otherFunction()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Or writing a class, like this:

```
import sys

class MyClass():

    def otherFunction(self):
        print self.tecE

    def main(self, argv):
        self.tecE = 'test'
        self.otherFunction() # Calling other class members (using the self object which actually acting like the "this" keyword in other languages like in Java and similars)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   myObj = MyClass()  # Instantiating an object out of your class
   myObj.main(sys.argv[1:])
```

> So how and where to define self?

You will use self:

1. As the first argument of your class methods `def my_method(self, arg1, arg2):`
2. Within the class to refer to any other class members (just as demonstrated above) `self.do_job("something", 123)`
3. For creating class members: `self.new_field = 56` Usually in `__init__()` constructor method

Note: decalring a class variable without the `self.new_var`, will create a static class variable.

Comment: In your first example, you can simply use the keyword global instead of using a dictionary.

Comment: I don't think you should encourage OP to use `self` outside of a class. They already think it means something it doesn't (although it's not clear what). Use a different name.